# What's the adjective for feeling intense cold pain? (while at the dentist)

Tags: vocabulary, adjective

What's the adjective for feeling intense cold/pain? (while at the dentist)

I hear this all the time when I get a dental cleaning, but I haven't been able to find the word in a dictionary.

It roughly sounds like 시릴 수 있어요. ("This might hurt/feel cold.")

Comment: I wonder how this question got 255 views in 11 hours, when out site traffic is like 82 visits per day

Comment: @busukxuan did it get on the 'Hot network questions' list? This one did, for some reason : http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/548/what-is-the-politest-way-in-korean-to-say-that-someone-is-old. Both of them look superficially interesting to non Korean learners from the titles (I edited mine to specify 'Korean' later)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word you are looking for is 시리다, meaning *chilly* or *achingly/painfully cold*. Rather than *cold pain* where *cold* complements and characterizes the *pain*, this one is the other way round: it is more directly about the *cold* that is characterized by *pain*. *시릴 수 있어요* would, as you might expect, mean *It might get painfully cold*. The word is usually used to describe sensations of parts of the body, often in contact with something cold, e.g. teeth. Since you can't find it in a dictionary, here's an entry on [Naver Dictionary](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=23450800).

Comment: I was so close; I wonder why I couldn't find it before... I think it's because Google translate totally fails on 시리다

Comment: @Leftium Wiktionary doesn't seem to have an entry either.